# Invalid division by 0 in powerapps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I tried the below code for handling error,  but still receiving error in powerapps

```
If(IsBlankOrError(If(Rim.Value= true,Round(ValueA/ValueB,0),Round(ValueC/ValueB,0))),"0",
 If(Rim.Value= true,
Round(ValueA/ValueB,0),
    Round(ValueC/ValueB,0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right that ISBLANKORERROR() should be handling the error internally rather than propagating the error and crashing.  I will bet that the problem is that you alternate response, "0", is TEXT instead of VALUE.  Your intended response, i.e., when ValueB is a number and not zero is going to be a number.  According to the docs, to use IFERROR() or ISBLANKORERRROR(), the alternate response and the intended response need to be the same type.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-iferror#type-compatibility

Comment: Yes, I agree with you should be related to data type, Value A & C are calculated values and are taken from "Text Label" with data type as number, Value B is taken from "text input", I tried converting to a number but still receiving the error. Also when I see Value A & C data type is shown as "Control".